# How to display child elements using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my code:

```js
function f1() {
  document.getElementById("a1").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("b1").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function f2() {
  document.getElementById("b1").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("a2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("a1").value;
  document.getElementById("a2").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("a1").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function f3() {
  document.getElementById("a2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("i1").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<h4>Monday</h4>
<input id="a1" style="visibility: hidden;" placeholder="enter time slot"></input><button id="b1" type="submit" onclick="f2()" style="visibility: hidden;">Submit</button>
<div id="a2" class="vi" style="display:none;background-color:#94DCE5 ;width: 172px;">10:00 AM - 02:00 PM><img src="assets/close" id="i1" onclick="f3()" /></div><br>
<a href="#" onclick="f1()">Add new session</a> JavaScript functions:
```

I have some links and when i click on them i want them to take some input which I'm doing using input tag and submit button. After the submission I wish to display the text submitted using a div element. But the problem is that initially I've set the visibility of that div to hidden and as soon as submit button is clicked it should be visible displaying the text entered.

Also I have an image tag inside that hidden div .I'm able to display the text entered using the div but the problem is that the image is not displayed.The image is of a closing icon which i need for further functionality.

Comment: Can you put the code in stackoverflow code snippet? so that we can understand it better of what is really happening

Comment: you need to add the file extension at the and of the image name in `src` attribute of the `img` element

Comment: @Yousaf I tried that still not working

Comment: @KiranGhumare check out my answer I think this is what you wanted. By accepted answer you have to keep time in the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the entire div's contents, including the img tag.  You should create a new element for inserting the text.  You also didn't reshow the img on adding the text.

```js
function f1() {
  document.getElementById("a1").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("b1").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function f2() {
  document.getElementById("b1").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("c2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("a1").value;
  document.getElementById("a2").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("a1").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("i1").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function f3() {
  document.getElementById("a2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("i1").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<h4>Monday</h4>
<input id="a1" style="visibility: hidden;" placeholder="enter time slot"></input><button id="b1" type="submit" onclick="f2()" style="visibility: hidden;">Submit</button>
<div id="a2" class="vi" style="display:none;background-color:#94DCE5 ;width: 172px;">10:00 AM - 02:00 PM<img src="assets/close" id="i1" onclick="f3()" /><span id="c2"></span></div><br>
<a href="#" onclick="f1()">Add new session</a> JavaScript functions:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing all the element's contents with the new value. Try `+=` instead of `=` to keep the existing elements:

```
document.getElementById("a2").innerHTML += document.getElementById("a1").value;
```

Code Example:

```js
function f1(){
  document.getElementById("a1").style.visibility="visible";
  document.getElementById("b1").style.visibility="visible";
}
function f2(){
  document.getElementById("b1").style.visibility="hidden";
  document.getElementById("a2").innerHTML += document.getElementById("a1").value;
  document.getElementById("a2").style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("a1").style.visibility="hidden";
}
function f3(){
  document.getElementById("a2").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("i1").style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

```html
<h4>Monday</h4>

<input id="a1"  style="visibility: hidden;" placeholder="enter time slot"></input><button id="b1" 
type="submit" onclick="f2()"style="visibility: hidden;">Submit</button>
<div id="a2" class="vi" style="display:none;background-color:#94DCE5 ;width: 172px;">10:00 AM - 
02:00 PM><img src="assets/close" id="i1" onclick="f3()"/></div><br>

<a href="#"  onclick="f1()">Add new session</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function f1() {
  document.getElementById("a1").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("b1").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function f2() {
  document.getElementById("b1").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("sessionText").innerHTML = document.getElementById("a1").value;
  document.getElementById("a2").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("a1").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function f3() {
  document.getElementById("a2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("i1").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<h4>Monday</h4>
<input id="a1" style="visibility: hidden;" placeholder="enter time slot"></input><button id="b1" type="submit" onclick="f2()" style="visibility: hidden;">Submit</button>
<div id="a2" class="vi" style="display:none;background-color:#94DCE5 ;width: 172px;"><span id="sessionText"></span>10:00 AM - 02:00 PM &nbsp;<span class="close" id="i1" onclick="f3()">&times;</span></div><br>
<a href="#" onclick="f1()">Add new session</a> JavaScript functions:
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it what you exactly wanted here that, only value `10:00 AM - 02:00 PM` should be changed. For this to happen mention that time **10:00 AM - 02:00 PM** in `<span></span>` tag and then by specifying it an id you can achieve it

**Change your code to**

```js
       function f1(){
    document.getElementById("a1").style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById("b1").style.visibility="visible";



    }
   function f2(){
    document.getElementById("b1").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML=document.getElementById("a1").value;
    document.getElementById("a2").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("a1").style.visibility="hidden";


   }
   function f3(){
   document.getElementById("a2").style.display="none";
   document.getElementById("i1").style.visibility="hidden";

   }
```

```html
 <h4>Monday</h4>

    <input id="a1"  style="visibility: hidden;" placeholder="enter time slot">
    <button id="b1" 
    type="submit" onclick="f2()" style="visibility: hidden;">Submit</button>
    <div id="a2" class="vi" style="display:none;width: 172px;"><span id="abc">10:00 AM - 
    02:00 PM</span><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" id="i1" onclick="f3()"></div><br>

    <a href="#"  onclick="f1()">Add new session</a>
```